# Trigger click on both top and bottom stacked components at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, event-handling, click

I have a component which have two child components. Eg: A and B. A is given `position: absolute` and placed on top of B like an Overlay. Also A have higher `z-index`. A and B have onClick events attached to them

My question is, can a single click be passed down through A to B?. For example if I click on A, I need to invoke A's onClick event first and then pass the click event to B and trigger B's onClick event.

Some conditions are there

- Cannot call B's onClick event directly.
- the touch/click event should be passed through A to B

this needs to done in **React-native**. Folks what do you think. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass component B reference inside A

```js
class App extends React.Component {
   
   render () {
     const b = <B />
     const a = <A b={b} />

     return (
       <div>
         {a}
         {b}
       </div>
     );
   }
}


class A extends React.Component {
   
   onClick = (e) => {
      console.log('Clicked A');
      this.props.b.onClick(e);
   }
   render () {
     return (
       <div onClick={this.onClick}>
         A
       </div>
     );
   }
}


class B extends React.Component {
   
   onClick = (e) => {
      console.log('Clicked B');
   }
   render () {

     return (
       <div onClick={this.onClick}>
         B
       </div>
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have edited my  questions. I cannot call B's onClick event since it is invoked by a library component